# Why does this subquery work in SQL Server but not SQLite?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

This query gives the desired results on SQL Server but not in SQLite.

Desired result: return all letters that are not used in vocabulary words.

```
SELECT letter 
FROM alphabet
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT word 
  FROM vocabulary
  WHERE word LIKE '%'+ letter + '%')
```

On SQL Server all the unused letters are returned, but on SQLite every letter (row in alphabet) is returned.

Do you know how I can get the desired result in SQLite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQLite uses `||` to concatenate. What you're doing is addition.